# Ajax call on Editview field of sugarcrm to database to check it status (not working)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, sugarcrm

I have two custom modules X and Y. I want to make an AJAX call in `Editview` of Y Module which have unique value common Text field with X module. So when should I add value in Y module it should check in database where this record is checked with primary option or not in X module and returns "true" or "false"?

I have written an on-change function for this in `view.edit.php` of Y module but seems to not be working.

Here is my code:

```js
//view.edit.php
<script type="text/javascript">

  function icueid_onchange (){
    var connectionObject = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest (“GET”, “getid.php”, callback);
    YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady(“EditView”,function () {ldelim} initEditView(document.forms.EditView);
    initCall();
    {});
  }

</script>
```

and in `editviewdef` of Y module, I have the following code:

```
array (
  'name' => 'primary_book_i_cue_id',
  'label' => 'LBL_PRIMARY_BOOK_I_CUE_ID',
  'displayParams' => 
    array (
      'field' => 
      array (
        'onchange' => 'icueid_onchange();',
      ),
    ),
```

while Loading window in console, I am getting

> "SyntaxError: illegal character"`

where the arrow pointed towards 'GET'.

I am a beginner in AJAX request. So please take me to the corner.

Comment: Your question is horrible asked. But your problem is that you are not using the correct quote characters you use `“ ”` but you have to use `"` or `'`. Your problem likely occured when you copy pasted something from somewhere.

Comment: EJTH thanks for your comment but after using correct  " " near GET still my control is not reaching upto "getid.php" can you please help me out. Thanks in advance